How to display transparent GIFs using AutoHotkey script when pressing CapsLock?
I am trying to create a script in which if you press the capslock key a gif image appears on the screen, but the gif image appears with a solid black background, it is not transparent, what am I doing wrong?
; Variable to track the state of Caps Lock
global capslock_toggle := false

; Path to the GIF file with transparency
ImagePath := "C:\Path\To\Your\Folder\animation.gif"

; Path to ffplay (adjust this line with the path to ffplay.exe)
ffplayPath := "C:\FFmpeg\bin\ffplay.exe"

; Variable to store the ID of the ffplay process
global ffplayPID

; Function to show the GIF using ffplay
ShowImage() {
    global
    Run, %ffplayPath% -autoexit -loop 0 -vf "format=rgba" -x 200 -y 200 -noborder -window_title "GifWindow" %ImagePath%,, Hide, ffplayPID
}

; Function to hide the GIF by closing ffplay
HideImage() {
    global
    if (ffplayPID) {
        Process, Close, %ffplayPID%
        ffplayPID := ""
    }
}

; Detect Caps Lock key press and toggle actions
CapsLock::
capslock_toggle := !capslock_toggle
if capslock_toggle
{
    ShowImage()  ; Show the GIF
}
else
{
    HideImage()  ; Hide the GIF
}
Return


enter image description here
I try to convert gif to webm but it doesn't work either

does ffplay display the image correclty with transparency when run manually (not using autohotkey)?

No, it keeps the solid black background, but my gif is supposed to have transparency.

if ffplay doesn't work without autohotkey, why would it work with autohotkey? in other words, why is the question about autohotkey at all? It's not immediately obvious that ffplay can do what you want. might be better to ask on softwarerecs for a program that can overlay a transparent image on the Windows desktop. for linux, there are programs like pqiv but I don't use windows. Perhaps QuickView-3.0

use the quick view without autohotkey and the gif works correctly with animation and transparency. but when you run it from autohotkey it only shows a white circle with the title ''view'' in the center
